# Weak Wi-Fi signal on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS. Works great on windows 8

Tags: networking, 16.04, drivers, wireless, ralink

Experiencing poor wifi signal on Ubuntu 16.04. I tried other linux too. It is the same there as well. I have installed the compatible driver for my system, but still with no luck. Here is the result of running `sudo lshw -C network`

```
network  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: 54:35:30:20:c3:9b
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=4.8.0-36-generic firmware=0.37 ip=192.168.0.102 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:18 memory:d3610000-d361ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0f:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 0c
       serial: a0:1d:48:fa:4d:34
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:28 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:d3500000-d3500fff memory:d3400000-d3403fff
```

Any steps to improve the speed/signal strength is very much appreciable as I mostly work on Ubuntu. Let me know if you need any additional details to troubleshoot the same.

I am also attaching the results of running `wireless info script` below:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 01 Apr 2017 18:10 IST +0530

Booted last: 01 Apr 2017 00:00 IST +0530

Script from: 25 Mar 2017 07:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.8.0-36-generic #36~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sun Feb 5 09:39:57 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
    DeviceName: Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi Adapter
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]

0f:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
    DeviceName: Hanksville Gbe Lan Connection
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [103c:1963]

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f2:b40d Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 138a:0050 Validity Sensors, Inc. Swipe Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
rt2800pci              16384  0
rt2800mmio             20480  1 rt2800pci
rt2800lib              94208  2 rt2800mmio,rt2800pci
rt2x00pci              16384  1 rt2800pci
rt2x00mmio             16384  2 rt2800mmio,rt2800pci
rt2x00lib              57344  5 rt2800lib,rt2x00pci,rt2800mmio,rt2x00mmio,rt2800pci
mac80211              761856  3 rt2800lib,rt2x00pci,rt2x00lib
cfg80211              581632  2 rt2x00lib,mac80211
eeprom_93cx6           16384  1 rt2800pci
wmi                    16384  1 hp_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eno1' [IF1]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:25706 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:25706 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:1609383 (1.6 MB)  TX bytes:1609383 (1.6 MB)

wlo1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlo1' [IF2]>  
          inet addr:192.168.0.102  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::4c36:4385:682b:ce84/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:35994 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:29998 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:34469333 (34.4 MB)  TX bytes:5316715 (5.3 MB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Ividam Swargamanu"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.452 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'Ividam Swargamanu' [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate=52 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=38/70  Signal level=-72 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:133  Invalid misc:170   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlo1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlo1
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlo1

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       998     1  0 12:07 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlo1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Ralink corp.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe (Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rt2800pci
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.8.0-36-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlo1' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:07:00.0/net/wlo1
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlo1
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Ividam Swargamanu 2
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       90d19cc6-d515-49ec-980b-2947edf2e22c
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     52 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{1,2}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   940a071c-c8be-4763-8582-14afc54b8c48 | Ividam Swargamanu 1
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[2]:   90d19cc6-d515-49ec-980b-2947edf2e22c | Ividam Swargamanu 2
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.0.102/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.0.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       expiry = 1491056796
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 7200
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       ip_address = 192.168.0.102
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       routers = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.0.255
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       domain_name_servers = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       network_number = 192.168.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.0.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::4c36:4385:682b:ce84/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eno1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'eno1' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.6/0000:0f:00.0/net/eno1
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

SSID                BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY   ACTIVE  * 
Ividam Swargamanu   <MAC 'Ividam Swargamanu' [AC1]>  Infra  9     2452 MHz  54 Mbit/s  48      ▂▄__  WPA2       yes     * 
SaurabhHome         <MAC 'SaurabhHome' [AC2]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  20      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2  no        
Babu Reddy          <MAC 'Babu Reddy' [AC3]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  14      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2  no        
MGMNT               <MAC 'MGMNT' [AC4]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  14      ▂___  WEP        no        
It's not free_nkjs  <MAC 'It's not free_nkjs' [AN5]>  Infra  5     2432 MHz  54 Mbit/s  10      ▂___  WPA1       no        

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Ividam Swargamanu]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Ividam Swargamanu | type=wifi | permissions=user:ubuntu:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlo1' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Ividam Swargamanu
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Ividam Swargamanu 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Ividam Swargamanu 1 | type=wifi | permissions=user:thomas:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlo1' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Ividam Swargamanu
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Ividam Swargamanu 2]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Ividam Swargamanu 2 | type=wifi | permissions=user:thomas:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlo1' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Ividam Swargamanu
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

eno1      no frequency information.

wlo1      14 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 14 : 2.484 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

eno1      Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      3   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)

wlo1      Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'Ividam Swargamanu' [AC1]>
                    Channel:9
                    Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)
                    Quality=38/70  Signal level=-72 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Ividam Swargamanu"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000001ba40840bb
                    Extra: Last beacon: 12ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'SaurabhHome' [AC2]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=20/70  Signal level=-90 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"SaurabhHome"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000001ba4883173
                    Extra: Last beacon: 4240ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 03 - Address: <MAC 'Babu Reddy' [AC3]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=18/70  Signal level=-92 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Babu Reddy"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000001ae5f4a8c2
                    Extra: Last beacon: 12ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 04 - Address: <MAC 'MGMNT' [AC4]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=18/70  Signal level=-92 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"MGMNT"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000001ae5f4cbd0
                    Extra: Last beacon: 12ms ago

##### module infos ######################

[rt2800pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00/rt2800pci.ko
license:        GPL
firmware:       rt2860.bin
description:    Ralink RT2800 PCI & PCMCIA Wireless LAN driver.
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     4D2CAAE95D28B3DF4F72A52
depends:        rt2x00lib,rt2800lib,rt2800mmio,rt2x00mmio,rt2x00pci,eeprom_93cx6
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption. (bool)

[rt2800mmio]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00/rt2800mmio.ko
license:        GPL
description:    rt2800 MMIO library
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     DBE617B0243C0FEB62786D4
depends:        rt2800lib,rt2x00lib,rt2x00mmio
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[rt2800lib]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00/rt2800lib.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Ralink RT2800 library
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com, Bartlomiej Zolnierkiewicz
srcversion:     7092408A4EF1A70FC0C7538
depends:        rt2x00lib,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[rt2x00pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00/rt2x00pci.ko
license:        GPL
description:    rt2x00 pci library
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     D84965563CC7530CFFD2269
depends:        rt2x00lib,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[rt2x00mmio]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00/rt2x00mmio.ko
license:        GPL
description:    rt2x00 mmio library
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     02CA9DA77FC2C7FCCC58176
depends:        rt2x00lib
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[rt2x00lib]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00/rt2x00lib.ko
license:        GPL
description:    rt2x00 library
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     CF930122B7900096FC259FA
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     C63473656FCDBBDA56E12DA
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     F170FED576AF12B070D2E69
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[rt2800pci]
nohwcrypt: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[ 5985.293328] r8169 0000:0f:00.0 eno1: link down
[ 5986.643028] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[ 5986.787078] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eno1: link is not ready
[ 5986.832284] r8169 0000:0f:00.0 eno1: link down
[ 5986.832390] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eno1: link is not ready
[ 5986.893495] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
[ 5988.126586] wlo1: authenticate with <MAC 'Ividam Swargamanu' [AC1]>
[ 5988.137153] wlo1: send auth to <MAC 'Ividam Swargamanu' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 5988.138976] wlo1: authenticated
[ 5988.141084] wlo1: associate with <MAC 'Ividam Swargamanu' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 5988.144624] wlo1: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'Ividam Swargamanu' [AC1]> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=2)
[ 5988.144691] wlo1: associated
[ 5988.144727] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlo1: link becomes ready
[ 6015.227690] wlo1: authenticate with <MAC 'Ividam Swargamanu' [AC1]>
[ 6015.251237] wlo1: send auth to <MAC 'Ividam Swargamanu' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 6015.253117] wlo1: authenticated
[ 6015.255086] wlo1: associate with <MAC 'Ividam Swargamanu' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 6015.258656] wlo1: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'Ividam Swargamanu' [AC1]> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=2)
[ 6015.258727] wlo1: associated
[ 6074.896381] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 0 failed to flush (repeated 3 times)
[ 6096.992967] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 6139.041889] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 0 failed to flush (repeated 16 times)
[ 6282.483420] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush (repeated 24 times)
[ 6764.796914] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 0 failed to flush
[ 6764.997274] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush (repeated 3 times)

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Could you please try the steps in [this answer](/a/762244/175814)? Thanks.